# Does electric field generated by changing magnetic flux generate an opposing magnetic field?

Tags: maxwell-equations

According to Faraday's law a changing flux through a loop will create an Electric-field curling around that loop. And if the loop is a conducting wire the current looping will create an opposing magnetic field as below(Lenz):

[image]

But what if there is no wire and no current but just the circulating/looping Electric-filed around an imaginary loop? Would that Electric field generate an opposing magnetic filed as well?

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's correction to Ampere's Law states:

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

Even when $\mathbf{J}=0$, we still could have nonzero $\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$, which generates a magnetic field. Without this correction, propagation of electromagnetic waves would be impossible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62129/discussion-on-answer-by-probably-someone-does-electric-field-generated-by-changi).

Comment: But would this magnetic field you mention, be opposing to magnet's field? like the magnetic field in original faraday experiment opposes motion magnet....because if it is really so then moving a magnet in just air will produce opposing force which is impossible

Comment: @Amit Rai, see answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/808189/283846

There will indeed be an opposing force, the radiative reaction.